# Duvida para "checkar" um radiobutton ao clicar em uma imagem

Tags: delphi, imagem, delphi-7, object-pascal

Eu tenho essas 3 imagens com 3 `RadioButtons` diferentes, eu gostaria de ao clicar na imagem do quadrado em branco por exemplo, o respectivo `RadioButton` ficar selecionado.

Usei `radiobutton3.checked` no evento `OnClick` da imagem mas não funcionou.

Na imagem está três retângulos pintados de forma diferente, com `RadioButtons` ao lado de cada uma. Nenhum deles está marcado como selecionado.

[image]

Comment: Fiz exatamente o que disse e funcionou direitinho aqui pra mim, se tiver como poste uns trechos de códigos para ajudar mais.

Comment: Gabriel, caso a resposta do @Tmc não resolva, [edit] sua pergunta e posta o código que esta utilizando, qual componente de imagem utilizado ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para fazer isso basta tal como já referiu adicionar o seguinte código no evento `onclick` da `imagem3`, e o *RadioButton* passará a **check**:

```
procedure TForm1.Image3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  radiobutton3.Checked := True;
end;
```

Outra coisa que pode ser feita é passar os outros *RadioButtons* a `false`, bastando para isso acrescentar o seguinte código:

```
procedure TForm1.Image3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  radiobutton1.Checked := False;
  radiobutton2.Checked := False;
  radiobutton3.Checked := True;
end;
```

Se tiver alguma dúvida mais coloque.

Answer (score 2):

Implementa o seguinte código:

```
procedure TForm1.Image1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RadioButton1.Checked := Sender = Image1;
  RadioButton2.Checked := Sender = Image2;
  RadioButton3.Checked := Sender = Image3;
end;
```